# Android Studio Quiz App No Checked Radiobutton

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

Hi Good day there this is my conditions in my Button next my problem is i have a toast that if nothing is selected in a radiogroup then it will pop up a message but it doesnt do anything and when i press next it goes to the next question
what i wanted is when the radiobuttons is not selected it will just pop up a message and the questions will be just the same and it wont be going to the next questions here is the code i use i think the problem is where i place the condition to check if it doesnt have any checked answer idk really please help me

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
                if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[flag2])) {
                    while (numbers.contains(flag2)) {
                        flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
                    }
                    correct++;
                    coins++;
                }
                else if ((radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select an     Answer Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
                flag++;
                flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
                if (flag < questions.length)
                {
                    tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag2]);
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent inResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                    SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences("Game", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
                    editor.putInt("savedPlayerCredit", credit);
                    editor.putInt("savedPlayerCoins", coins);
                    editor.putInt("savedPlayerCorrect", correct);
                    editor.putInt("savedPlayerWrong", wrong);
                    editor.apply();
                    timer.cancel();
                    startActivity(inResult);
                    }
                }
            }

            );
        }
```

here is the whole code

```
package org.intercode.lifeatceu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class levelone extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv1, tvCred, tvQuestion, tvTimer;
    Button btNext;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;
    RadioGroup rg;
    LinearLayout ll;

    String questions [] = {"Ma. Cristina D. Padolina is CEU's President", "Carlito B. Olaer is the V.P of CEU", "CEU's VISION is to sting every enemy", "One of CEU's Mission is to promote creative and scholarly academic"};
    String answer [] = {"True", "False", "False", "True"};
    HashSet numbers = new HashSet();


    int flag = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int flag2 = 0 ;
    int correct = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    int coins = 0;
    int time = 0;
    int credit = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_levelone);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SharedPreferences loadGame = getSharedPreferences("Game", MODE_PRIVATE);
        credit = loadGame.getInt("savedPlayerCredit", 0);
        time = loadGame.getInt("savedPlayerTime", 0);


        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tvCred = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCred);
        tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        tvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);

        btNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNext);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
        numbers.add(flag2);
        tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag2]);
        tvCred.setText(String.valueOf(credit));

      final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000)
        {
            public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                tvTimer.setText ("Time remaining : " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                Intent inResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences("Game", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
                editor.putInt("savedPlayerCredit", credit);
                editor.putInt("savedPlayerCoins", coins);
                editor.putInt("savedPlayerCorrect", correct);
                editor.putInt("savedPlayerWrong", wrong);
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(inResult);
            }
        }.start();
        btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                                          String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
                                          if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[flag2])) {
                                              while (numbers.contains(flag2)) {
                                                  flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
                                              }
                                              correct++;
                                              coins++;
                                          }
                                  else if ((rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
                                       {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select an     Answer Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              wrong++;
                                          }
                                          flag++;
                                          flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
                                          if (flag < questions.length) {
                                              tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag2]);
                                              rb1.setChecked(false);
                                              rb2.setChecked(false);
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              Intent inResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                                              SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences("Game", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
                                              editor.putInt("savedPlayerCredit", credit);
                                              editor.putInt("savedPlayerCoins", coins);
                                              editor.putInt("savedPlayerCorrect", correct);
                                              editor.putInt("savedPlayerWrong", wrong);
                                              editor.apply();
                                              timer.cancel();
                                              startActivity(inResult);
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }

        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: are you using `RadioButton` with `RadioGroup` ..? can you please post your code ?

Comment: Check :  http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: alright hold on ill post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the condition in else if as it executes only if first if condition fails. Put it in a separate if condition and check.

```
if ((radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select an     Answer Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
       RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
       String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
       if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[flag2])) {
           while (numbers.contains(flag2)) {
                 flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
           }
           correct++;
           coins++;
       }
       else
       {
            wrong++;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String Id=String.valueOf(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

if(!Id.equals(null)){
   Intent.....
}else{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select an Answer Please",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I hope this will helpful to you.